# Have anybody tried to create local device lab for appium mobile app automation

Tags: java, selenium, testing, appium

I wanted to create a local device lab for Android App Testing, I have used Saucelabs and Browser Stack earlier, But I feel it's costly for me.

Have you tried any local device lab for Continous Integration and Development ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you try to do this you need to think at the maintenance cost.

You can discuss this with your client/team and bring and estimate of what would cost to create and maintain a local lab (Hardware + Software).

These cost should be part of the automation service and you can include them in the price and the client should pay.

You can have a presentation with the benefits of automation and the advantages and disadvantages of having a local lab vs using a cloud service.

Keep in mind that some issues take longer to fix and check if you afford a longer downtime of the CI environment.